# Python merge multiple date columes with null into 1 column Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to convert multiple dates format into YYYY-MM-DD, then merge them into 1 column ignore the NULL, but I end up with **TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[ 'Apr 2021'], ['Jan 1'], ['Fri'], [ 'Jan 18']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', ]) 

#convert Month date Jan 1
df['date1']=(pd.to_datetime('2021 '+ df['date'],errors='coerce',format='%Y %b %d'))

# convert Month Year Apr 2021
df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

#convert fri to this friday
today = datetime.date.today()
friday = today + datetime.timedelta( (4-today.weekday()) % 7 )
this_firday = friday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['date3']=df['date'].map({'Fri':this_firday})
df['date3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date3'])

df['dateFinal'] = df['date1'] + df['date2'] + df['date3']
```

I check the dtypes, they're all datetime, I don't know why. my approach is not efficient, feel free to let me know a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `bfill()` on `axis=1`:

```
df['dateFinal'] = df[['date1','date2','date3']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

OR

via `ffill()` on `axis=1`:

```
df['dateFinal'] = df[['date1','date2','date3']].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
```

OR

via `stack()`+`to_numpy()`

```
df['dateFinal'] = df[['date1','date2','date3']].stack().to_numpy()
```

output of `df`:

```
       date      date1      date2      date3  dateFinal
0  Apr 2021        NaT 2021-04-01        NaT 2021-04-01
1     Jan 1 2021-01-01        NaT        NaT 2021-01-01
2       Fri        NaT        NaT 2021-08-13 2021-08-13
3    Jan 18 2021-01-18        NaT        NaT 2021-01-18
```

Comment: update my feedback: after use it in my real data, it turn out that,  the 3rd way  give me ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. I checked and still don't know why, But the first way work perfectly